# Trouble using TypeScript project references in a pnpm monorepo

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to convert an existing, large monorepo to use TS project references, and as a proof concept I've created a simpler version: https://github.com/adc-mhaugen/mono-tsconfig, containing two libraries (./addons) and one application (./apps), each with sub projects for code (addon/app) and tests (test).

Each of the three projects has a tsconfig.json file which includes the two sub-projects tsconfig.json (src and tests) via project references, and each tests subproject includes it's src sub-project tsconfig.json via project references.

The second library (add-two) includes the first library (add-one) via project reference, and the application (app-one) includes both libraries via project reference.

The libraries work fine, the tests can see the src code, and add-two can see add-one.  The application can see both add-one and add-two, but the application tests sub-project cannot see the application source imports (`app-one/app` and `config` in https://github.com/adc-mhaugen/mono-tsconfig/blob/main/apps/app-one/tests/test-helper.ts), and I cannot for the life of me see why that would be.

Does anybody see anything wrong with my configuration?  Thanks for looking!